# How to set delay in a setInterval loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is part of my codes:

```
$('#monitor').click(function(){
            setInterval(function(){
                    $('#status_table tr [id^="monitor_"]:checked').each(function () {
                        monitoring($(this).parents('tr'));
                     });
                },15000);
        });
```

I want to call the function `monitoring` for each row in a table that has its checkbox checked. if i only have one, it is working fine. But when i have more than one, it jumbles up, which means it will not append the correct status in the table.
Here is my function `monitoring`:

```
       function monitoring($row) {
            fbType = $row.find('td:nth-child(3)').html();
            fbNum = $row.find('td:nth-child(4)').html();
            eachStatus =$row.find('td:nth-child(5)').attr('id');
            $('#ptest').append(fbType + ' '+ fbNum+' '+ eachStatus +'<br>');

            $.post('/request', {inputText: fbNum,key_pressed: fbType.toString()}).done(function (reply) {
                if (reply == "on") {
                    $('#status_table tr #'+eachStatus).empty().append("on");

                } else if (reply =="off") {
                    $('#status_table tr #'+eachStatus).empty().append("off");

                }
            });
        }
```

How can i delay the function call for each row? i tried the following

```
       $('#monitor').click(function(){
            setInterval(function(){
                    $('#status_table tr [id^="monitor_"]:checked').each(function () {
                       setTimeout(function(){
                            monitoring($(this).parents('tr'));
                       });
                     },1000);
                },15000);
        });
```

But the div #ptest displays `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just delaying them together, that's why they still run together. What you want is to delay them *from each other*.

```
$('#monitor').click(function(){

  //a jQuery object is like an array
  var checked = $('#status_table tr [id^="monitor_"]:checked');

  (function loop(i){

    //monitor element at index i
    monitoring($(checked[i]).parent('tr'));

    //delay
    setTimeout(function(){
      //when incremented i is less than the number of rows, call loop for next index
      if(++i<checked.length) loop(i);
    },15000);

  }(0)); //start with 0

});
```

Comment: thanks! it works but i need to loop it over. May i ask what is `(0);//start with 0` for?

Comment: i created another loop using setInterval. but when the number of row reduces (the table is dynamic), it will continue to find those initial rows and jumbles up.

Comment: @yvonnezoe `loop` is a function, and the `(0)` immediately invokes it with the argument `0`. It's like calling defining `loop` and calling it in one go. After 15 seconds, it calls itself again, now with 1 and does this until all values in `checked` are used. I used `setTimeout` rather than set interval for a more concise control.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. i will be adding another setInterval at the outside so  that the whole process can repeat itself. but as the table is dynamic, is it possible to set the duration to be a variable?

Comment: @yvonnezoe the duration can be placed in a variable outside the function, which you can change.

Comment: in this case http://jsfiddle.net/qJdaA/2/ , where should i put the variable if i would want the duration to be equal to checked.length*4000 instead of index*4000? i've tried almost everywhere but it doesn't work :/ i tried `var len=checked.length` then set the duration as `len*4000`

Answer (score 2):

Replace your following line:

```
monitoring($(this).parents('tr'));
```

for this one:

```
monitoring($(this).parent('tr'));
```

Comment: that gave me undefined undefined undefined instead of the fbType, fbNum, and eachStatus.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    monitoring($(this).closest('tr'));
},1000);
```

Comment: ah yes, it was a typo. i wanted to edit my question but stackoverflow was overloading just now.